# AWS Lambda with Winston logger throws Runtime.ImportModuleError

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, winston

I am trying to implement a Winston logger (version 3.2.1) inside an AWS Lambda. Following this [comment](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1250#issuecomment-452128291) I have this code:

```js
const winston = require('winston');

const waitForLogger = async (logger) => {
  const loggerDone = new Promise((resolve) => logger.on('finish', resolve));
  logger.end();
  return loggerDone;
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console(),
    ],
  });
  logger.log('info', 'some message');
  await waitForLogger(logger);

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: 'test passed',
  };
};
```

But after generating the build using Rollup and deploying the function using Terraform and testing it on the AWS console, I get this error:

```html
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module './has-flag.js'",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module './has-flag.js'",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:45:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
    "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
    "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)",
    "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"
  ]
}
```

Looking at the different modules, I find the 'has-flag' is required by 'colors' module which in fact is a dependency of 'winston'.

Comment: Are you zipping up all the dependencies into the deployment package you upload to Lambda?

Comment: No, I upload a zip with the bundle generated by Rollup (using 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve').

Comment: I have finally solved this error changing the Rollup configuration. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1607
anyway, I am also not able to bundle Winston

Answer (score 0):

Just to notice that [Bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) logging library works well with Rollup and I have been able to create the AWS Lambda bundle and tested the logging successfully.